# Why does Python 3 print statement appear to alter a variable, declared later in the code, but works fine without it?

Tags: python-3.x, printing, tuples

I am running Python 3.6.2 on Windows 10 and was learning about the zip() function.

I wanted to print part of the object returned by the zip() function.

## Here is my code, without the troublesome print statement:

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")

b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica", "Vicky")

x = zip(a, b)

tup = tuple(x)

print(tup)

print(type(tup))

print(len(tup))

print(tup[1])
```

## Here is my code with the troublesome print statement:

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")

b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica", "Vicky")

x = zip(a, b)

print(tuple(x)[1])

tup = tuple(x)

print(tup)

print(type(tup))

print(len(tup))

print(tup[1])
```

## The print(tuple(x)[1]) statement appears to change the tuple 'tup' into a zero-length one and causes the print(tup[1]) to fail later in the code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line, you create an iterator:

```
x = zip(a, b)
```

Within the print statement, you convert the iterator to a tuple. This tuple has 3 elements. This exhausts the iterator and anytime you call it afterwards, it will return no further elements.

Therefore, upon your creation of `tup`, your iterator does not return an element. Hence, you have a tuple with length 0. And of course, this will raise an exception when you try to access the element with index 1.

For testing, consider this:

```
a = ("John", "Charles", "Mike")

b = ("Jenny", "Christy", "Monica", "Vicky")

x = zip(a, b)

tup1 = tuple(x)
tup2 = tuple(x)

print(tup1)
print(tup2)
```

It will give you the following result:

```
(('John', 'Jenny'), ('Charles', 'Christy'), ('Mike', 'Monica'))
()
```

This is basically what you do when creating a tuple out of an iterator twice.

Comment: DocDriven - Thanks for you excellent and speedy explanation, with example. This is the first time I have used this service and am most impressed.

Comment: @ChrisBon: You are welcome. You might consider accepting this answer so that other users can see that your issue has been resolved.

Comment: I would like to 'accept' your answer, as you suggest, but I don't know how to do that. I cannot see an 'Accept' button. It is probably very obvious - but I cannot see it - can you guide me, please?

Comment: @ChrisBon: thank you, have a look at the arrow right above/below (I cannot remember) the upvotes/downvotes of my post.

Comment: Ah - found it - the "Tick mark" - Not very obvious, to me anyway - Thanks again.